# Would it be possible to make two columns which belong to different series respectively to be placed exactly on the tick on x-axis with highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

The following picture is my desired result (each of the column belongs to different series):
[image: This picture is my desired result]

When [there is only one series in the chart](http://jsfiddle.net/vwew2er2/10/), it is an achievable result; but when [there are two series in the chart](http://jsfiddle.net/vwew2er2/12/), the positions of the bars are skewed (not exactly on tick).

The only difference between these two charts is:

```
        {
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            data: finArray,    //position not skewed as this series has the same data as the other series
            pointWidth: argPWidth
        }]
```

and

```
        {
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            pointPlacement: 'on',
            data: finArray1,
            pointWidth: argPWidth
        }]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that disabling `grouping` should solve your problem:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
    xAxis: {
    min: 0.5,
    max: 2.5,
    tickInterval: 1
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false
    }
  },
  series: [{
    data: [
      [1, 5]
    ]
  }, {
    data: [
      [2, 2]
    ]
  }]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mohhq9rz/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping